# Can paritytech/parity be used as a library the same way that go-ethereum can be used in Go?

Tags: parity, library, rust

The `go-ethereum` project is divided into a set of standalone libraries that can be used in any Go project (e.g. smart contract interaction, keystore management, common cryptography and hex utils)

Can the same be done using the `paritytech/parity` project code or is it not structured in such a way that it can be easily used for external projects?

P.S. Are there any other projects/libraries that someone interested in both Rust and Ethereum should know about?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/pull/8412